# Including ComplexExpr and ComplexFunc classes in Halide API

Tags: halide

The ComplexExpr and ComplexFunc classes in the links below seem very convenient to work with complex numbers. Is there a plan to include them into the official Halide API? Or is there a reason why they are not included?

https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/apps/fft/complex.h

https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/be1269b15f4ba8b83df5fa0ef1ae507017fe1a69/apps/fft/funct.h

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as a Halide developer...

> Or is there a reason why they are not included?

We haven't included these historically since we didn't want to bless a particular representation for complex numbers. There are a few valid ways of dealing with them and the headers in question are just one.

> Is there a plan to include them into the official Halide API?

We've started talking about packaging some of this type of code into a set of header-only "Halide tools" libraries, so named to avoid the normative implication of calling it something like "stdlib". So as of right now, there is no concrete *plan*, but the odds are nonzero.

In the meantime, the code is MIT licensed, so you should feel free to use those files, regardless.